# Best database storage for matching products from offers

Tags: database, data-structures, nosql, relational-database, storage

I have following problem. I have products, offers and their parameters (in MySQL about 300 000 000 rows). Based on offer parameters and their rate (parameters are dynamic and every parameter type has different rate) I must join offers to product. Of course there will be a lot of updates, deletes or inserts (for example around 5000req/s).

Second functionality will be sending these connected information via api. Anyone have any recommendations what NoSQL, relational database or something similar to use for storage?

### Edit

I'll show my example on a small sample of data in MySQL:

```
Offer

+----------+-----------------+
| offer_id |      name       |
+----------+-----------------+
|        1 | iphone_se_black |
|        2 | iphone_se_red   |
|        3 | iphone_se_white |
+----------+-----------------+

Parameter_rating
+--------------+----------------+--------+
| parameter_id | parameter_name | rating |
+--------------+----------------+--------+
|            1 | os             |     10 |
|            2 | processor      |     10 |
|            3 | ram            |     10 |
|            4 | color          |      1 |
+--------------+----------------+--------+


Parameter value
+----+--------------+----------------+
| id | parameter_id |     value      |
+----+--------------+----------------+
|  1 |            1 | iOS            |
|  2 |            2 | some_processor |
|  3 |            3 | 2GB            |
|  4 |            4 | black          |
|  5 |            4 | red            |
|  6 |            4 | white          |
+----+--------------+----------------+

Parameter_to_value
+----------+--------------------+
| offer_id | parameter_value_id |
+----------+--------------------+
|        1 |                  1 |
|        1 |                  2 |
|        1 |                  3 |
|        1 |                  4 |
|        2 |                  1 |
|        2 |                  2 |
|        2 |                  3 |
|        2 |                  5 |
|        3 |                  1 |
|        3 |                  2 |
|        3 |                  3 |
|        3 |                  6 |
+----------+--------------------+
```

and based on this data I must return that bids 1,2 and 3 are one product.
The biggest problem is that data often changes. For example, changing prices, removing offers, etc. Therefore, I do not think that MySQL is the most suitable technology and I try to choose another.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Please provide more detail, like a concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Platform

> any recommendations what NoSQL, relational database or something similar to use for storage?
>
> Therefore, I do not think that MySQL is the most suitable technology and I try to choose another.

All that is ordinary fare for a Relational database. Tens of thousands of banks run trading and pricing systems that are extremely active from hundreds of thousands of users, on such systems.  Every day.  The changes you allude to are normal on such systems (eg. pricing and pricing basis, change all the time, in response to Buys & Sells).

But they use genuine SQL platforms.  Freeware/shareware/vapourware/nowhere suites such as MySQL and PostgreSQL are neither SQL-compliant, nor viable platforms for high-throughput OLTP systems (no server architecture; no ACID Transactions; etc).  They are still implementing the basics that SQL platforms have had since 1984, which is very difficult (impossible!) because they do not have a server architecture.

Therefore MySQL and PostgreSQL are not suitable for the reason of abject performance; zero concurrency; etc, and not for any database design concerns.

For an appreciation of the value of a genuine **OLTP Server Architecture**, refer to [Oracle vs Sybase ASE](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Oracle%20Circus/Oracle%20vs%20Sybase.pdf).  Although the article deals with Oracle explicitly, it applies to all freeware because all freeware has the same non-architecture that Oracle has.  Actually, even less than Oracle.  You get what you pay for.

#### Data Analysis

<sub>This answer is limited to Relational databases; SQL, its designated data sublanguage; and a genuine, commercially viable, SQL platform.</sub>

It appears the system supports an auction of some kind, which means you have to maintain an inventory of available/sold items.  The database design that is required is quite ordinary.

However, your question is not clear enough to be answered.  You are making many assumptions, that we are not party to.  Allow me to ask some leading questions, which you need to consider and answer (update your Question):

- what are the fundamental **things** that the systems transacts operations against ?
  (products such as phones ?)
- how are those things **identified** ?
  (Not the `ID` but how do humans identify each thing)
- what are the **properties** of those things ?
  (please, not "parameter" ... maybe `OS; RAM; Processor; Colour`) ?
  Then property values can be understood
  (You can't mess with the attributes of a thing unless you hold and maintain the thing)
- what are the **operations** or **transactions** against those things

  - (a) internal or admin transactions
    (eg. AddProperty; AddPropertyValue; AddProduct; etc)
  - (b) external or online user transactions
    (eg. BidProduct [offer to buy]; CloseBid; etc)
- who are the **operators**, to which those transactions are permitted ?
  (eg. Admins; product suppliers; online bidders; etc)
- I can't make any sense of your `Parameter_to_value`, please explain
- What is `rating` ?  Some kind of weighting for the property vs the other properties, or something the bidders declare ?

#### Database Design • Tentative

[image: XWizardER]

- This might take a few iterations.
- Don't worry about `ID` fields on each and every file: first we have to understand the data, how it relates to other data, and how it is identified.  We can add `ID` fields at the end.

#### Note

- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/), the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading for beginners.
- The [IDEF1X Anatomy](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Model%20Anatomy.pdf) is a refresher for those who have lapsed.
- If you have trouble *reading* the Predicates from the Data Model, let me know and I will produce them in text form.